# TeXworks references in included tex files show as [?]

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am try to set up TeXworks on Windows to write my thesis, but have hit a problem with creating a shared bibliography in a two-tier document hierarchy.

I have a main `thesis.tex` file which sets up the packages and then includes chapters, and finally a bibliography. The `collection.bib` file is in the folder above `thesis.tex`, and chapters are in subfolders.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{../uolthesis}
%\usepackage{alltt,float}
%\usepackage{lgrind}
\usepackage{url}                    % for better handling of URL
\usepackage{lscape}                 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption2}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{../draft_doc}

\graphicspath{{ch1/}{ch2/}}

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical}
% use less hyphenation
\lesshyphenation
% or totally stop it
%\nohyphenation

% speed up compilation
%\includeonly{ch1/ch1}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{thesis title}
\cite{Santner2010,Kalal2011}    % This works
\include{ch1/ch1}               % \cite{} in here produces [?]
\include{ch2/ch2}               % \cite{} in here produces [?]

\clearpage
\markboth{References}{References}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
{\bibliography{../collection}}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that `\cite{}` from within `thesis.tex` work correctly, but the same citations in the chapter tex files produce `[?]`. The bibliography produced correctly contains all cited papers, so the problem is *only* in getting the numeric references are the citation point.

The log file is, predictably, full of lines like

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Santner2010' on page 9 undefined on input line 61.
```

I am compiling with `pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTeX`. I've tried compiling multiple times without success.

What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you (or TeXWorks) run `biber` or `bibtex` at all?

Comment: Yes, bibtex is being run. I found an error in the log "I couldn't open database file collection.bib". It looks like the directory structure is confusing it?

Comment: Try `\bibliography{../collection}`, or move the `.bib` to the same folder as the `.tex`.

Comment: `\bibliography{../collection}` is what I have (typo in the example!) and references in the main tex file work. It is failing while processing chapters from a subfolder because the relative path is now wrong. I tried `\bibliography{../collection,../../collection}` but that doesn't work either

Comment: I've tried a fixed path rather than a relative path to the bibliography and still get the same results; works for top level tex but not included tex's, so it isn't a path problem after all :(

Comment: can you make your MWE more minimal? it's hard for anyone to test things when custom document classes etc are used..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the two custom elements included in your MWE - the `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{../uolthesis}` documentclass and whatever is in your `\usepackage{../draft_doc}` package.

<strike>Using the standard `report` class and commenting the mentioned usepackage line (as well as getting rid of the stuff relating to hyphenation) yields the following which behaves perfectly fine:</strike>
With the `uolthesis` class (from OP's comment) I can reproduce the error with the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{../uolthesis}

\begin{filecontents}{ch1/ch1.tex}
\chapter{ch1}
this is include file 1. citing \cite{citekey}.
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{ch2/ch2.tex}
\chapter{ch2}
this is include file 2. also citing \cite{citekey}.
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{../collection.bib}
@article{citekey,
    author = "Bloggs, Joseph K.",
    journal = "International Journal of Dubious Assertions",
    pages = "337-629",
    title = "Misusing Scientific Terminology for Fun and Profit",
    volume = "202",
    year = "1950"
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\chapter*{thesis title}
This cites \cite{citekey}.    % This works
\include{ch1/ch1}             % This works too!
\include{ch2/ch2}             % As does this..

\clearpage
\markboth{References}{References}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
{\bibliography{../collection}}

\end{document}
```

and commenting the line:

```
\RequirePackage{chapterbib}         % create bibiography for each chapter
```

solves the problem.

Refer to [the documentation of `chapterbib`](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/cite/chapterbib.pdf) as to why this behaviour would occur and how to use the package if separate bibliographies are needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've narrowed it to the contents of uolthesis.tex, which I've put on pastebin at http://pastebin.com/eNBvSNUS what's the best way to diagnose where the problem is? #newbie

Comment: testing is best done by commenting the vast majority of that file and looking for which part makes the citations fail, especially checking the combinations of packages included.
in your case the problem seems to be with the `chapterbib` package loaded by the `uolthesis` class - commenting the corresponding line does the trick for me. I'll update my answer correspondingly.